# In an intrinsic pure semiconductor like Silicon, would the effective mass of electrons and holes be identical?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

In a pure semiconductor where fermi-level lies right exactly in the middle, I was told that n = p = ni. Based on the equations below, I concluded then that the effective mass of electrons and holes has to be equal for the n and p to be equal to one another. But it seems that this is not the case?? My questions is does effective mass of electrons equal to effective mass of holes in undoped case with fermi-level in the middle of the band gap? I would assume that effective electron mass and holes only differs in doped cases where fermi levels would shift from the middle of the gap.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The effective mass has to do with the curvature of the bands. Hence the 'light' hole and 'heavy' hole split off valence bands, for example.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this so you are saying so would they be identical? That was my question and I have been going back and forth on this for days.

Comment: Why do you think that the Fermi level has to be in the middle of the band gap?

Comment: Im here with the same question, which arose after reading the first sentence on page 208 of Kittel's solid state. "If m_hole =m_electron, then mu = 1/2 E_gap..."

Answer (score 1):

The effective mass is in general a tensor, with

$ {1 \over m^{*}_{ij}} = {1 \over \hbar^{2}}{\partial^{2}$E(k) \over \partial  k_{i} \partial k_{j}}$

(see, for example, Sze's Physics of Semiconductor Devices, pg. 14 in the second edition).

The effective mass in silicon for electrons is 0.98, while the light hole is 0.16 and the heavy hole is 0.49. These values are already integrated into the full derivation of both the Fermi level for an intrinsic semiconductor as well as the intrinsic carrier densities.

Comment: So you are saying even in intrinsic ones the effective holes and electrons mass is different?

Comment: Absolutely- the curvatures of the bands are different.

Comment: Well then it does not make sense to me that the N_c is equal to N_v in intrinsic semiconductors because N_c and N_v both include the effective mass of electrons and holes (m_n and m_p)  Hence n should not equal to p in intrinsic semiconductors.  Mathematically it does not make sense to me.

Comment: @CuriousJ - You are perhaps looking at it the wrong way. Look, $n$ has to be equal to $p$ in intrinsic semiconductors - any electron in the conduction band came out of a hole in the valence band - there is a one-to-one causation of each. Now, the shapes of the bands and thus the effective mass have an impact on exactly where the Fermi level is such that $n$ can equal $p$. Does that make more sense?